# How can I change server time in sql command line (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to changed a server time of SQL Server 2008 but I must be use it on sql command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All system date and time values are derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)